# What is the time complexity of this "longest decreasing subsequence" algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, time, time-complexity

I'm looking for the longest decreasing subsequence of integers in an array. Here I'm using a binary search (which I know is O(logn)), so I figured this code must be O(nlogn). I tried my code on this particular input and it runs in 0.02 seconds. Now, I was searching on the internet and I found this code http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/dynamic_programming/lds. The author says it takes O(n^2), but on my same input, it actually takes 0.01 seconds to run, which is obviously less than my O(nlogn) algorithm.

```
def binary_search(arr, l, r, x):

    while r-l > 1:
        m = l + (r - l) // 2
        if arr[m] >= x:
            r = m
        else:
            l = m
    return r


def longest_decr_subseq_length(array, size):

    table = [0 for i in range(size + 1)]

    table[0] = array[n-1]
    length = 1

    for i in range(size - 1, -1, -1):
        if array[i] < table[0]:
            table[0] = array[i]
        elif array[i] > table[length - 1]:
            table[length] = array[i]
            length += 1
        else:
            table[binary_search(table, -1, length - 1, array[i])] = array[i]

    return length


lis = [38, 20, 15, 30, 90, 14, 6, 17]
n = len(lis)

print(longest_decr_subseq_length(lis, n))
```

So, is my algorithm O(n^2), too? Or is it normal that those are the running time? I'm sorry if the question appears silly, but I'm new to algorithms and still a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity isn't the same as execution time. It means how execution time will grow as the input data grows. So even with lower time complexity, it may take longer to execute on the same amount of data, but when you increase the amount of input data algorithm with lower time complexity will start working much faster.
As for the complexity of your algorithm, your calculation seems to be correct, it should be O(nlogn)

Comment: you did not provide the complexity of the algorithm of the OP, though

Comment: I'm so sorry...What's OP?

Comment: @pippi2424 OP = "Original Poster", this means you, who posted the original question